# Python Scope and Nonlocal Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I'm new to Python and a little confused with the whole nonlocal thing. Here's the problem snippet of code:

```
        positon = 0b0
        while True:
            pos_choice = input("\tPlease enter your choice: ").lower()
            if pos_choice == '1':
                position = position | Baseball.pitcher
                break
            elif pos_choice == '2':
                position = position | Baseball.catcher
                break
            elif (pos_choice == 'd') and (position != 0b0):
                break
            elif (pos_choice == 'd') and (position == 0b0):
                print("\tChoose a position.")
            else:
                print("Invalid choice.")
        print(position)
```

So this throws me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "driver.py", line 252, in <module>
load_student()
File "driver.py", line 142, in load_student
position = position | Baseball.catcher
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'position' referenced before assignment
```

Based upon what I've read on answers to other questions, the problem would be because the problematic "position" is nested two loops in from the original call (is that right?).

My main problem is that I can't figure out how to bind the two "position"s using nonlocal, though I have tried various solutions to no avail. Also, is using nonlocal a taboo like it is when using global? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. In the declaration, the variable is spelled `positon` instead of `position`.

Comment: Oh Jesus, that's so embarrassing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple typo in your first line.

Comment: Oh Jesus, that's so embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry that happens to every programmer and the that is what SO for: you have a bug you don't see but some fresh eyes do.